# Looking for ideas to bring another git repository code to a Github repo periodically

Tags: git

I have two git repositories, and they cannot be associated in any way.

- **Source**: contains the code that I need to bring once a day
- **Destination**: A GitHub repository that includes a mixed code, including what comes from the source.

Every day, I manually pull the code from the source, copy all the file to the destination git directory and push/merge it to the destination. The merge is straight forward. The source always overwrites changes in the destination.

I have a feeling that I am not doing this right. I expect I am missing some of the git abilities, and there is a smarter way of doing this.

Is there a better or more efficient way of doing what I am doing?

Comment: Write a shell script to do what you're describing.

Comment: This sounds like a potential use for [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)